# Java JDK issue or any thing else

Tags: java, coldfusion, virtualbox

I have working to setup an project on local. I have used **Virtual Box** because **VMWare Fusion** is available for MAC and I am working on windows. During the  process when I run “**vagrant up --provider=virtualbox**” commend then **JDK 7** error was displayed error screenshot is given below
http://prntscr.com/m7jp7e

After that I have installed “**Oracle JDK 8**” on **/usr/lib/jvm/** path manually on **virtual box Linux** and then run vagrant up command then again **JDK 8** issue is displayed. 
I have also changed the path of **java_home**  and **jdk_version** in  “coldfusion-server.rb” file.
Please have a look error screenshot below.
Error Screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/9OQC3iLold2r

[image]

Comment: It is preferrable to post error messages as *text* (not images). Screen shots aren't searchable, so it is harder for others with the same error to find the answer.

Comment: What version of CF are you installing? Which version of CF are you trying to emulate?What Vagrant image are you using to start your CF server? And are you aware of Oracle's Java licensing changes that may impact whatever you're developing for? https://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2018/11/15/on_production_use_of_java_going_forward

Comment: And while I agree with using VirtualBox over VMWare, I believe that VMWare Fusion is available for both Mac and Windows, too. I guess it would depend on what virtual images you were trying to use. Also, I would point out that there's CommandBox (https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox), which is often a much better option for general development.

Answer (score 1):

Mac user here! Highly recommend using CommandBox to run any version of Adobe ColdFusion on a Mac. Much easier to deal with than VirtualBox or manual installation. The only issues you might encounter is with older versions of ACF that run on JRun showing errors in CF Admin related to JRun specific references. Nothing to really worry about.

You can change the JDK and other settings used by CommendBox using `server.json`:

```
{
    "name":"ACF Application",
    "jvm":{
        "javaHome":"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home",
        "heapSize":2048,
        "minHeapSize":1024,
        "args":"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
    },
    "app":{
        "cfengine":"adobe@9.0.2+282541",
        "serverHomeDirectory":"serverHome"
    }
}
```

These are some of the settings I have to run a legacy ACF 9 on my Mac using an older JDK with non-default memory settings. See [Configuring Your Server](https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/embedded-server/configuring-your-server) for more info.